Kafka Connect SqlServer Configuration (SSL)
I have a connector of JdbcSourceConnector that try to connect to SQL Server Database by using the next config in the url "encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;" because of its an old version and its required to connect.
I realized that this only works by executing update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY on my docker container shell but now that I migrate to production with SSL all over Kafka ecosystem the above command affects security and don't leave connect or even see the brokers instead of only affect the connector or driver (this happens after the execution of the command, before that all it's working properly).
I'm just thinking how to overcome those issues. Any advices? Maybe configuring the Java base image of my docker container? All suggestions are welcome.
{
    "name": "ssqlsource",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://mydb:1433;databaseName=user;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;",
        "connection.user": "user",
        "connection.password": "password",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "timestamp.column.name": "addDate",  
        "topic.prefix": "sn_user",
        "table.whitelist": "user.dbo.sn_user",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.user",
        "transforms": "route",
        "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
        "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
    }
}

Regards,
Rigoberto C.

I'd suggest ignoring kafka connect and research how JDBC driver you're using can use SSL. For example, do you need a cert file? You'll need to mount one in the containers (server and client)

@OneCricketeer Thanks for your the suggestion. I'll take a look into how use SSL on the driver.

What sql server version are you connecting to? What's the errors you're getting if you remove encrypt=false? You should be able to get TLS 1.2 going for a lot of older servers

I'm getting the next errors:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints".
Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA
I don't know the version. Sadly, its a database of a supplier and I can see all the details. I just know that it's an older version. @siggemannen

Also, in the java.security has the next arguments:
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1.1, DTLSv1.0, RC4, DES, 
MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, 
ECDH

The problem on production was the certifcates doesn't match with the host used on my JdbcSourceConfig configuration. If they match you will be able to use  update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
Note. Don't forget to be careful with the security, it's better to use a different approach to handle this situation instead of what I'm applying.
And also set your logger level correctly because mine was not properly configured and that was the reason why I didn't catch the error before.
Regards,
